# read user input into array until user enter specific entry

Tags: bash, shell-script, input, read

i need to create a bash that get input from user and insert them into an array until user enter an specific thing. for example, if i run script:

```
enter variables: 3 4 7 8 ok
```

i get this array: `array=( 3 4 7 8 )`

or:

```
enter variables: 15 9 0 24 36 8 1 ok
```

i get this array: `array=( 15 9 0 24 36 8 1 )`

how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newline as the default separator:

```
read -a array -p "enter variables: "
```

If you want a different character than newline, e.g. `y`:

```
read -a array -d y -p "enter variables: "
```

You can only use a single character as delimiter with `read`.

**EDIT:**

A solution that works with the `ok` delimiter:

```
a=
delim="ok"
printf "enter variables: "
while [ "$a" != "${a%$delim}${delim}" ]; do
    read -n1         # read one character
    a="${a}${REPLY}" # append character
done
array=(${a%$delim})  # remove "ok" and convert to array
unset a delim        # cleanup
echo                 # add newline for following output
```

**Note:** This version also accepts input of the form `3 4 7 8ok` (without the last space character), 
but line editing with special characters like <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> doesn't work. They're treated as raw input.

Comment: i put `echo $array` in my bash for test and it only returned first value.

Comment: You need to `echo "${array[@]}"`. With `$array` you get the first value like with `${array[0]}`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The `ok` does not seem to matter, and it is left in the array.

Comment: @Kusalananda It does if the newline or the `y` is the "specific thing" (`ok`).

Comment: @Kusalananda Added a version for the `ok` delimiter.